# how to use uiswitch for selecting category in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

Trying to create an if else statement for a `UISwitch`. Not exactly sure what goes in the if else statements to check whether the switch is on or off.

```
@IBAction func selectionLabel(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(<some condition>)
    // do something

    else
      //do something
}
```

Is this a correct way to use the switch?

Comment: No. `if(true)` is always true. End of story. You are not actually testing anything useful.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sender` is the switch.  Check if the switch is on by checking the `on` property:

```
@IBAction func selectionLabel(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let mySwitch = sender as? UISwitch {
        if mySwitch.on {
            // switch is on
        } else {
            // switch is off
        }
    }
}
```